# how to compare two dates and time, EXP: 07/10/2015 12:30 to 08/10/2015 02:00 in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, time, compare

```
 NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[timeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm"];

NSDate *startDate = [timeFormatter1 dateFromString:@"07/10/2015 12:30"];

NSDate *EndDate = [timeFormatter1 dateFromString:@"08/10/2015 02:30"];


if([startDate compare:EndDate] == NSOrderedAscending)

    return YES;

 else

    return NO;
```

i'm following Above code, But every time output was wrong result(going to "return No").

At same time EXP: 07/10/2015 12:30 to 07/10/2015 23:30 this was working.

i need to at a time two formats working.

Please help me?

Comment: I think that you have wrong `timeFormatter1`. May be you have missed it with `timeFormatter`. And in startDate and EndDate is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in year format. Use "yyyy" instead "YYYY" to fix issue.

Here the working code:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [timeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSDate *startDate = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"07/10/2015 12:30"];

    NSDate *EndDate = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"08/10/2015 02:30"];


    if([startDate compare:EndDate] == NSOrderedAscending)

        NSLog(@"Ascending");

    else

        NSLog(@"Descending");
```

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Check this link for more date formats

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3A) of NSDate compare:

Returns an NSComparisonResult value that indicates the temporal ordering of the receiver and another given date.

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Parameters anotherDate

The date with which to compare the receiver. This value must not be nil. If the value is nil, the behavior is undefined and may change in future versions of Mac OS X.

Return Value

If:

The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other,  NSOrderedSame

The receiver is later in time than anotherDate,  NSOrderedDescending

The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate,  NSOrderedAscending
In other words:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame) ...
```

Note that it might be easier in your particular case to read and write this :

```
if ([date2 isEqualToDate:date2]) ...
```

See [Apple Documentation about this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate%3A)